# При старте метода окно не отвечает Java FX

Tags: java, android, javafx

Создал визуализированное управление сервером. Только вот незадача. Про нажатии кнопки запуска окно перестаёт отвечать (производится запуск метода `Server.socketStart()`) и сверху пишется Server(Не отвечает), в консоли сервер запускается. Как реализовать так, чтоб окно не зависело запуска метода, или метод изменял состояние элементов GUI.
На данный момент придумал запускать советы в отдельном потоке, однако задаётся вопрос: Как корректно остановить сервер?
Останавливаю пока так:

```
Server.socketDisconnect(){
    socketServer.close();
    socket.close()
}
```

Но это способ кривой т.к. по мимо становки сервера выкидывает экспекшен.

Где можно прочитать про изменение Java FX при запуске метода из другого класса?

Comment: Есть такая вещь как `потоки`. Может дело в них? =)  Собственно, нужно код смотреть, что в классах и как работаете с ними.

Answer (score 1):

> На данный момент придумал запускать советы в отдельном потоке

Да, все верно. Для этого в JavaFX есть отдельный класс [Task < T>](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), при реализации которого необходимо переопределить метод `T call() throws Exception`, в котором необходимо реализовать логику старта сервера.

Рекомендую так же почитать про использование этого [класса](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm).

> Но это способ кривой т.к. по мимо становки сервера выкидывает
>   экспекшен.

Ну значит надо обработать этот эксепшн так, как требует ваша логика.

```
Server.socketDisconnect(){
    try {
        socketServer.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //не удалость закрыть серверный сокет
    }
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //не удалость закрыть сокет
    } 
}
```